# jQuery ui map interaction from infoWindow/marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am preparing a jQuery/google map to list all houses in my database. All works ok.
 
Now I added a `DIV` in the content of the marker infoWindow which on mouseouver triggers a `Style` background-color change on the house info in the sidebar of the page were all houses are listed..

The gmap gets the content from `<li data-gmapping='{"id":"30","latlng":{"lat": 40.161833,"lng":-7.943697},"tags":"drupal","desc":"mycontent"}'>`

I inserted inside the "desc":

```
<div onmouseover=\"highlight_id('.$ranking.')\" onmouseout=\"highlight_id_x('.$ranking.')\">'.$name.'<br />More info soon!</div>
```

Managed to escape the brackets `\"` and my `DIV`makes the style change I want. 
Is there a better way to put the content inside the infoWindow?

The map jQuery code:

```
$(function() { 
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    $("[data-gmapping]").each(function(i,el) {
                        var data = $(el).data('gmapping');
                        self.addMarker({'id': data.id, 'tags':data.tags, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(data.latlng.lat, data.latlng.lng), 'bounds':true }, function(map,marker) {
                            $(el).click(function() {
                                $(marker).triggerEvent('click');
                            });
                        }).click(function() {
                            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': data.desc }, this);
                        });
                    });                     
                }});
            }).load();
```

Question:

- How to do the same on the marker hover? How/Were to add a onmouseover javascript function?

Comment: I managed to make a "mouseover" work over the map_canvas but no sucess over the marker... `$('#map_canvas').mouseover(function() {alert ("Works");});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!, i got it now.

I am using a jQuery plugin for Google maps ([more info here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)).

then added `.mouseover(function() {/*code*/})` just before `.click(function({self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': data.desc }, this);`
                            });`  in my case to change the background of a DIV outside the map.

The total code now is:

```
$(function() { 
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    $("[data-gmapping]").each(function(i,el) {
                        var data = $(el).data('gmapping');
                        self.addMarker({'id': data.id, 'tags':data.tags, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(data.latlng.lat, data.latlng.lng), 'bounds':true }, 
                            function(map,marker) {
                            $(el).click(function() {
                                $(marker).triggerEvent('click');
                            });
                        })
                        .mouseover(function() {document.getElementById("rank_" + data.id).style.backgroundColor="#FFAAAA";})
                        .mouseout(function() {document.getElementById("rank_" + data.id).style.backgroundColor="#333333";})
                        .click(function() {
                            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': data.desc }, this);
                        });
                    });                     
                }});
            }).load();
```

Hope this helps other, now I can see which of my items is the gmap-marker related to by highlighting its div background.